# How to represent longText in Angular interface

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I have this interface:

```
export interface Employee1 {
   id: number;
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   description: ;
}
```

decription in the interface has longText data type.

I want description to be an editor (WYSIWYG) like summernote.

How do I represent longText on interface since it's beyond a string?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, should rather be tagged with TypeScript, but there is no such thing as "LongString" in the language. A string in TypeScript/JavaScript can be as long as the available memory permits.

Comment: See the description in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length). The maximum length of a string in javascript is dependant on browser and javascript version - not the type used. always use `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **string** type for 'description' like other properties. It can store upto 2^53 - 1 elements.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description) for reference.

> ECMAScript 2016 (ed. 7) established a maximum length of 2^53 - 1 elements. Previously, no maximum length was specified. In Firefox, strings have a maximum length of 2**30 - 2 (~1GB). In versions prior to Firefox 65, the maximum length was 2**28 - 1 (~256MB).

Comment: What I mean is WYSIWYG (Editors). For example summernote

Comment: You can use **string** or **any** type